# How to push my JSON data that are displayed in HTML into a final jsonString

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, push

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCMju.png)In my index.html I display in 5 divs some JSON data(data in JSON format):

```
<div id="InformationJson" class="messages-container1">{}</div>
<div id="DataJson" class="messages-container2">{}</div>
<div id="RulesJson" class="messages-container3">{}</div>
<div id="WorkitemsJson" class="messages-container4">{}</div>
<div id="LanguageJson" class="messages-container5">{}</div>
```

In my separate function of my JavaScript code I want to push all my JSON data from these 5 divs in a var named `jsonString`, which will be a final array.

This will be my jsonString implementation:

```
var jsonString = [push1,push2, push3, push4, push5];
```

How will I push them all together?

Comment: what is a,b,c,d and e . can you specify?

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. What data are you trying to add? What is your expected output?

Comment: a,b,c,d,e will be my JSON strings after pushing them inside jsonString. I try to add my json strings that are displayed in my .html in a final jsonString

Comment: Do you know the difference between a JavaScript object and a JSON string?  Do you mean the text content of those elements (represented by the `{}` ) in your markups?

Comment: Exactly that is what I want to save in my jsonString. Everything is inside {} which I displayed in my 5 divs

Comment: The only thing I want is to push all my JSON data in jsonString.

Comment: I uploaded this screenshot to show you the format of the text of my divs that I want to push in jsonString @MarkSchultheiss. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see no correlation between the screenshot and your question, please add more details or clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of those `div`s may look like JSON to you but, to the computer, they're just strings and will be treated as such.

The most straightforward way to collect them into a larger JSON formatted string would be to convert the strings into Javascript objects via [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), insert those objects into a containing object, then convert the whole thing into a string via [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Extending your intent, you might have something like:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify([
  JSON.parse(push1),
  JSON.parse(push2),
  JSON.parse(push3),
  JSON.parse(push4),
  JSON.parse(push5)
]);
```

---

To answer your add-on question of how to extract the content of the `div`s, it might go like this:

```
var push1 = document.getElementById('InformationJson').textContent;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.One last question.  Regarding push1, It is the string which is saved in <div id="InformationJson" class="messages-container1">{}</div>. How will I make JSON.parse(push1) please?

Comment: @webenginious Are you asking how to extract the JSON string content from the `div`s?